# How can I parse an int from a CloudFormation log using a metric filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

My system is creating the following log entries:

> INFO(updateEndpointAssignments) "0 assignments are being saved"
>   INFO(updateEndpointAssignments) "4 assignments are being saved"
>   INFO(updateEndpointAssignments) "333 assignments are being saved"

How can I parse the number out of the string for use as a metric?

I am trying the following filter pattern:

```
[prefix = "INFO(updateEndpointAssignments) \"", myCount, suffix = "
assignments are being saved\""]
```

But have had no luck so far.

Can anyone help?